# Updating OSM map from within PhoneGap/Cordova App

Tags: openstreetmap, gps, phonegap, cordova

I am trying to build a sat-nav application that allows the users to dynamically update the map that their application is using. So if the user updates the map with a new road then that road is considered in shortest path calculations.  I have become familiar with Postgres/PostGis databases, and importing osm data into them, but so far I have been unable to figure out a way that the user can update the map and the display the updates to the user. Could anyone offer me some advice on methods to achieve this ? ?

Comment: You need to keep your postgis data up to date (slim mode) see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Best_practices